# android Master/detail View in the same layout

Tags: android

how to implement a master detail view in the same layout in android as i explained in the image file. (the number of rows in the detail table is not equal for each master Item).

[image]

Comment: detail view gets visible when master view is clicked.right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ExpandableRecyclerview` for that purpose, that would be more efficient for your lists as like that image. Here are some resources. You can use the (so called) *master* as the `parentViewHolder` and *details* as `childViewHolder`

- https://acadgild.com/blog/expandable-recyclerview-in-android-with-examples
- https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: Thanks for your response, in this two links the detail view has equal items(fields in RecyclerView, e.g. all have 3 fields ) but in my project they are not equal. (e.g. one word has 5 examples and another word has 7 or 10 , 12 and etc. ) . So i think detail should be parametric , but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: then better you should have a look on basic recyclerview tutorial first, then start that. its pretty easy. https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: I tested links but i did not implement the master/detail dataset(data model) e.g country-->state, because the state numbers of each country aer different.